# Split TXT file into several files each X rows(using R)

Tags: r, split

I have a txt file ("JT.txt") with 10 mln rows. I want to split it in the simplest way into several files in the same directory by each 200.000 rows and call files names with pattern "JT_1.txt", "JT_2.txt", etc.
How can I do this using R?

Answer (score 1):

just sharing my logic here :

```
mtcars$rows <- 1:nrow(mtcars)  # create a index
mtcars$rows <- cumsum(mtcars$rows %% 2)  # this creates blocks of 2 rows

# now we just split it : I think , this should work. add write.table() inside lapply()
lapply(split(mtcars, mtcars$rows), function(x) paste0("mytext", unique(x[["rows"]]), ".csv"))
```

Comment: @ktatar156 does it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
#create a sequence of indices for splitting the data by increment of N
N = 6;

splitIndices = seq(1,nrow(mtcars),N)

#for each index, split dataset and export
lapply(splitIndices,function(x)  { 
    minIndex = x; 
    maxIndex = min(x+N-1,nrow(mtcars)); 
    DF = mtcars[minIndex:maxIndex,] 
    write.table(DF,paste0("JT_",1+as.integer(x/N),"_.txt"))
    } )
```